# Word 2016 Mail merge with hyperlink is changing the mergefield to the first hyperlink

Tags: hyperlink, ms-word, mailmerge

Creating the merge field and then merging the document works and the URL changes with each new record
 { HYPERLINK { MERGEFIELD "URL" } * MERGEFORMAT }

However if I close the Word template and re open it, the merge field has changed to
{ HYPERLINK "https://example.co.nz" }, inserting the URL for the first record

All records therefore have the same URL.

Comment: You might want to ask this in the end-user venue Super User as this is really off-topic on SO (has nothing to do with *creating* the field code). You might want to try *freezing* the fields before closing (Ctrl+F11) and unfreezing after opening (Ctrl+Shift+F11)

Comment: There have been several questions in this area, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428891/add-variable-hyperlink-in-mail-merge-in-word-2013 , and if you want your hyperlink fields to survive a save/close/reopen, especially when you have more than one of them, you’ll need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16817380/mailmerge-dynamic-hyperlink-fields-lost-after-save-reload-of-document-word-201

Comment: See *Mailmerge Hyperlink ‘Click Here’ Insertion* in the **Mailmerge Tips and Tricks** thread at: http://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html.